# drop the null column that contains a missing value less than the specific percent

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

i try to drop the null value for the columns that contains missing value less than five percent
for example i have theses columns

[image]

This percentage of missing value for each columns

and try to drop the null value use this code

```
df4 = df4.dropna(
    df4.loc[
        :, list((100 * (df4.isnull().sum() / len(df4.index)) <= 5))
    ].columns,
    1,
)
```

but unfortunately, i find this error

> unhashable type: 'Index'

Comment: anyone can help me ?